# Interchange the order of unordered summation and differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, summation

Let $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ and $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space $H$. Fix $x\in H$. I would like to show that $$[0,\infty)\to H\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-\lambda_nt}\langle x,e_n\rangle_He_n$$ is differentiable.

Note that we've got the following general result (which is obtained from integration under the integral sign with respect to the counting measure): If $I$ is nontrivial open subset of $\mathbb R$, $E$ is a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, $N$ is a nonempty set and $(f_n)_{n\in N}\subseteq E^I$ and $(f_n)_{n\in N}\subseteq E^I$ satisfies

1. $(f_n(t))_{n\in N}$ is absolutely summable for all $t\in I$;
2. $f_n$ is differentiable for all $n\in N$;
3. there is a summable $(h_n)_{n\in N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$ s.t. $\left\|f_n'\right\|_E\le h_n$ for all $n\in N$,

then $(f_n'(t))_{n\in N}$ is absolutely summable for all $t\in I$ and $$G:I\to E\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto\sum_{n\in N}f_n(t)$$ is differentiable with $$G'(t)=\sum_{n\in N}f_n'(t)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in I.$$

However, in the setting of the beginning of this post, this seems to require that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda_n<\infty$, unless I'm missing something ... So, how can we prove the desired claim?

*Remark*: It might be worth mentioning that in the particular instance of the problem that I'm interested in $((\lambda_n,e_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is the eigenpair sequence of the weak Laplacian on a bounded open subset of $\mathbb R^d$, $d\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Do uou have a good reason to think this is true? Seems implausible to me

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The reason why I think this is true is that in the situation of the remark at the end of my post, $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is precisely the heat semigroup which is known to be immediately differentiable.

Comment: Ok. Of course there you know that $\lambda_n$ is a certain eigenvalue; what makes the conjecture seem so unlikely is you're given _nothing_ about $\lambda_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(writing $\hat x(n)$ in place of $\langle x,e_n\rangle$.)

Choose $C$ so that $$te^{-t}\le C\quad(t\ge0).$$

So $$\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\le C/t\quad(\lambda,t>0),$$
hence if $K\subset(0,\infty)$ is compact then $$\lambda e^{-\lambda t}
\le C_K\quad(\lambda\ge0, t\in K).$$

So for  $N<M$ we have $$\sup_{t\in K}\left|\left|\sum_{n=N}^M\lambda_ne^{-\lambda_n t}\hat x(n)e_n\right|\right|\le C_K^2\sum_N^M|\hat x(n)|^2\to0\quad(N,M\to\infty).$$

So the differentiated series converges (in norm) uniformly on $K$, hence $G$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$:

> > **Exercise.** Suppose $E$ is a Banach space and $f_n:(0,1)\to E$ is continuously differentiable for $n=1,2,\dots$. If $f_n\to f$ uniformly and $f_n'\to g$ uniformly then $f$ is differentiable with $f'=g$.

I'm pretty sure this is true assuming just that $f_n$ is differentiable, but it's much easier as stated: show that $f(x)-f(y)=\int_y^x g$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've provided an additional answer, but I've accepted your answer, since you've provided the simple, but crucial, inequality that I was missing. However, especially since I'm not sure why you suggest that we need the exercise you gave before we can conclude, it would be great if you could check [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4165279/47771) and let me briefly know whether you agree or not.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Your version seems fine. Why do we need the Exercise above? Just before the Exercise I say "So A, hence B.". We need to know that A does imply B, which is exactly the Exercise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we only need to assume that $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$, since there's no need to exclude $0$.

As [David C. Ullrich](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/248223/david-c-ullrich) argued in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4164822/47771), we may use that $$\lambda e^{-\lambda t}<\frac1t\;\;\;\text{for all }t>0\text{ and }\lambda\ge0\tag1.$$

For clarity of exposition, let $$T(t)x:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-\lambda_nt}\langle x,e_n\rangle_He_n\;\;\;\text{for }x\in H\text{ and }t\ge0.$$ While this is not relevant for the question, it's worth nothing that $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is a well-defined contractive $C^0$-semigroup on $H$ and the actual target of my question is to show that $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is immediately differentiable, i.e. $T(t)H\subseteq\mathcal D(A)$ for all $t>0$, where $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ denotes the generator of $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$.

In order to show the desired claim we fix $t_0>0$ and $x\in E$. (I stress the fact that the subsequent argumentation won't hold for $t_0=0$, but I'm open for any comment on that in the comment section below this answer. But we shouldn't expect to be able to show the the claim for $t_0=0$, since this would clearly imply $\mathcal D(A)=H$.)

In order to show $T(t_0)x\in\mathcal D(A)$, we need to show that $\lim_{h\to0+}\frac{T(t_0+h)x-T(t_0)x}h=\lim_{h\to0+}\frac{T(h)T(t_0)x-T(t_0)x}h$ exists.

We cannot use the result mentioned in the question, but we can use the modified result stated below in *Lemma 1*. We choose $$f_n(t):=e^{-\lambda_nt}\langle x,e_n\rangle_He_n\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N.$$ Since $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is orthogonal, $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|f_n(t)\right\|_H^2\le\left\|x\right\|_H^2<\infty\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag2.$$

It's enough to consider an arbitrary neighborhood $I$ of $t_0$. So, let $\delta>0$ be arbitrary with $$I:=B_\delta(t_0)\subseteq(0,\infty).$$ Since $\overline I$ is compact, $$c:=\sup_{t\in I}\frac1t<\infty$$ and hence $$\left\|f_n'(t)\right\|_H\le c\left|\langle x,e_n\rangle_H\right|\tag3\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in I\text{ and }n\in\mathbb N$$ and since the right-hand side is square-summable we can apply *Lemma 1* and obtain that $$G:I\to\ell^2(\mathbb N;H)\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto(f_n(t))_{n\in\mathbb N}$$ is differentiable with $$G'(t)=(f_n'(t))_{n\in\mathbb N}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in I.\tag4$$ In particular, using the fact that a family of orthogonal elements in a Hilbert space is summable if and only if the corresponding family of squared norms is summable, we conclude that \begin{equation}\begin{split}\left\|\frac{T(t_0+h)x-T(t_0)x}h-\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}f_n'(t_0)\right\|_H^2&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|\frac{f_n(t_0+h)-f_n(t_0)}h-f_n'(t_0)\right\|_H^2\\&=\left\|\frac{G(t_0+h)-G(t_0)}h-G'(t_0)\right\|_{\ell^2(\mathbb N;\:H)}^2\xrightarrow{h\to0}0.\end{split}\tag5\end{equation}

---

**Lemma 1** Let $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ be nontrivial and open, $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, $N$ be a nonempty set, $p\ge1$ and $(f_n)_{n\in N}\subseteq E^I$ with

1. $(f_n(t))_{n\in N}\in\ell^p(N;E)$ for all $t\in I$;
2. $f_n$ is differentiable for all $n\in N$;
3. $\left\|f_n'\right\|_E\le h_n$ for all $n\in N$ for some $(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\ell^p(N)$,

then $$(f_n'(t))\in\ell^p(N;E)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in I\tag6$$ and $$G:I\to\ell^p(N;E)\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto(f_n(t))_{n\in N}$$ is differentiable with $$G'(t)=(f_n'(t))_{n\in N}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in I.\tag7$$

Comment: In (3) do you mean $||f_n'(t)||_E\le h_n$ for all $t$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich In order to use Lemma 1, we need to find $(h_n)\in\ell^p$ satisfying $\|f_n'(t)\|_H\le h_n$ and in $(3)$ I've shown that we can pick $h_n=c\left|\langle x,e_n\rangle_H\right|$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: That answers my question, yes. My issue was where you wrote $||f_n'||$ instead of $||f_n'(t)||$; of course $f_n\notin H$.